# used setTimeout generate a TypeError

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to time delay load used setTimeout, i had statement a varible and it is global.but it is generate a TypeError when i input content in the input tag;
i dont know why.

the code following:

```
var searchInvoiceTimer = null;
clearTimeout(searchInvoiceTimer);
searchInvoiceTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(1)
},1000)
```

the error following:

```
main.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: timeout.close is not a function
at exports.clearTimeout.exports.clearInterval (main.js:14)
at index.js:540
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at App.handleTaskChange (index.js:526)
at onChange (index.js:991)
at Object.executeOnChange (LinkedValueUtils.js:132)
at ReactDOMComponent._handleChange (ReactDOMInput.js:241)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:69)
at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js:85)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js:108)
```

Comment: Post more of your code, especially the global variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The code posted clearly won't cause the error listed, there must be more to it (such as an import).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be because of your IDE. Check if you have below import in your code.

```
import { clearInterval } from 'timers';
```

This is because of the auto-import feature of some IDE.
If you want to **disable this feature** you can simply fix it in your IDE setting.

```
"typescript.autoImportSuggestions.enabled": false
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but the reason is not this and I had found the question.thanks.

Comment: I already know the problem，the reason is I import 'import { clearInterval } from 'timers';' and after deleting it, the code is normal at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your code check you must have imported a `clearTimeout`

```
" import { clearInterval } from 'timers';
```

remove that and use the normal `clearTimeout` method.